# Extract distinct values from Dataframe and insert them into new Dataframe with same column Name

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Using python 3.7 , pandas 1.1.3 , Anaconda Jupyter Notebook

I am new into python and I have a following dataframe.

DF_1

```
Name  Date
AAA   2000-09-01
BBB   2001-08-01
CCC   2002-07-01
AAA   2005-05-01
```

I just want to extract distinct values from 'Name' column and create a new dataframe (df_2) and insert into it with same column name.

Output df_2 should look like this

```
Name
AAA
BBB
CCC
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
df_2 = DF_1[['Name']].drop_duplicates()
```

Comment: wow it works, May I know the reason for using two [[ ]] ?

Comment: Sure. With one brackets you're selecting `pd.Series` from DataFrame. With two brackets - you're selecting specific columns in the format of `pd.DataFrame`.

Comment: Make sure marking answer as correct if it helped :)

Answer (score 4):

How about:

```
DF_2 = pd.DataFrame(DF_1.Name.unique(), columns=['Name'])
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also do it using `np.unique` which is a little faster compared to `pd.Series.unique()` and `pd.Series.drop_duplicates()`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(np.unique(df_1['Name']),columns=['Name'])
```

Answer (score 1):

for that u may not need a dataframe series would be a perfect fit

```
df2=pd.Series(df['name'].unique(),name='name')
```

in case u want a dataframe here is another way of doing it

```
df.drop("num",axis=1).drop_duplicates()
```